# R: How do I sort integers across multiple columns?

Tags: r, sorting, sapply

## The dataframe. "temperatures"

```
date     temp1   temp2   temp3   temp4   temp5   temp6   temp7   temp8   nacolumn
1: dmYY     22      45      31      12      98      77      64      11      value
2: dmYY     ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      value
3: dmYY     04      02      10      16      14      12      08      06      value
```

## The result we are going for (sorted per row by column integer).

```
date     temp1   temp2   temp3   temp4   temp5   temp6   temp7   temp8   nacolumn
1: dmYY     11      12      22      31      45      64      77      98      value
2: dmYY     ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      value
3: dmYY     02      04      06      08      10      12      14      16      value
```

---

For plotting individual smoothed lines per-each-column over time, I am trying to re-order some (test) temperature data, the temp1 column being the lowest recorded : temp8 being the highest recorded.

#### *There are a few questions that don't quite cover what I'm looking for ->*

- [R: Sort Across/Horizontally [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644343/r-sort-across-horizontally)
- [Sort data by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861320/sort-data-by-row)

  > t(apply(temperatures[,2:9]
- [R: Calculate SD in each row over a selection of columns after removing minimum and maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637659/r-calculate-sd-in-each-row-over-a-selection-of-columns-after-removing-minimum-a)
- [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

  > temperatures[ order(temperatures[,2:9]

I hope this isn't terribly simple but, in the case it is, please let me know.

Comment: `temperatures[2:9] <- t(apply(temperatures[2:9], 1, sort))` ?

Comment: If it is a data.table, then try `df1[, (2:9) := as.list(sort(unlist(.SD))), .SDcols = 2:9, by = 1:nrow(df1)]`